# LOAD DATA INFILE is skipping ALL rows and no warnings

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I looked for a similar question but I could not find  a magic answer....so I'm hoping I'll find one now as this is driving me crazy!

I was going great guns with importing CSV data into MySQL...and **now suddenly I'm getting nothing but skipped records**. I ought to mention that I have been doing lots of deleting records (just experimenting really as I'm learning about MySQL and building my first database) so I've been chopping and changing the data including lots of copy/pasting in Excel, just in case any of this may be causing the trouble.

An example here, where I chopped the CSV down to just 2 records:

```
GENRE_NAME
Classic Rock
Electronica
```

The query to load the data:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'Music_All_2.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE genres COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' IGNORE 1 LINES (genre_name);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 2  Warnings: 0
```

And the table is empty (so it's not skipping them due to them already existing):

```
select * from genres;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Finally, here's the `SHOW CREATE TABLE genres` output:

```
genres | CREATE TABLE `genres` (
`genre_pk` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `genre_name` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`genre_pk`),
 UNIQUE KEY `genre_name` (`genre_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=255 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Thank you in advance to the solver of my problem, there is sooooo much I don't know - it's fun learning but frustrating at the same time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have 2 problems.

### 1. AUTO_INCREMENT value

In your DDL,

- `genre_pk` is TINYINT. So `genre_pk` can hold 0~255.
- in end of CREATE STATEMENT, `AUTO_INCREMENT=255`

  - This sets initial value for `genre_pk` to 255

### 2. LINES TERMINATED BY

You need to change `LINES TERMINATED BY` from '\r' to '\n'

### 3. Summary

I've tested following SQL, and it worked well.

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE `genres` (
`genre_pk` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `genre_name` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`genre_pk`),
 UNIQUE KEY `genre_name` (`genre_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**LOAD DATA**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/Music_All_2.csv'
INTO TABLE genres FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (genre_name);
```

### Reply to OP's comment

#### 1) How to reset AUTO_INCREMENTed value

- When table has data which shouldn't be deleted.

  ```
  ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = n;
  ```
- When existing data could be deleted. (this is what you've already tried)

  ```
  TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
  ```

#### 2) '\n' v.s '\r'

That's weird. Generally speaking,

- '\n' for Unix system
- '\r\n' for Windows system

I never heard about '\r' for carriage return. MySQL manaul(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) states that

> If you have generated the text file on a Windows system, you might have to use LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' to read the file properly, because Windows programs typically use two characters as a line terminator. Some programs, such as **WordPad**, might use \r as a line terminator when writing files. To read such files, use LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'.

Comment: this is great, thank you. I should've noticed those Auto-Increment numbers (I've got another table stuck on 65,535!)

Comment: Regarding my 2 problems: (1) Can I reset the `AUTO-INCREMENT` value rather than make the field length bigger? and (2) When I first tried LOAD DATA INFILE on my CSV, I was using `\n`, but it only worked when I switched it to `\r` - this data had been `<Ctrl-C>`d straight out of iTunes...

Comment: I used `TRUNCATE` to reset `AUTO-INCREMENT` and basically start again with my data; but `\n` seriously doesn't work for me! I got this result with the 2 records above (with my newly reset AUTO-`INCREMENT) Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0` ... but when I changed to `\r` the 2 records were added successfully.

Comment: @simien I've updated my answer ;-). Please feel free to upvote my answer if my answer helped you.

Comment: I was awaiting your reply about this pesky carriage return business! I'm on a new-ish Mac, using Office for Mac 2011. And `\r\n` doesn't work for me either (same non-result as `\n`).

Comment: @simien I'm glad to know new knowledge about '\r' and Mac! Thank you ;-)

Comment: `\r` is 'sorta' the standard record separator in CSV... Then again nothing in CSV is really standard anyway. It really is a very broken format but I guess we are stuck with it.